# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol static library

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2015, linker, name-mangling, tbar

I'm trying to link my C++ VS 2015 executable with tbarcode library 8. This library consists of header files, a lib file, and a dll file.

I keep on getting errors LNK 2019, for example LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_BCAlloc

I'm building in debug mode, I've added the lib to "Additional Depdencies" settings, its directory to "Additional Library Directories" and the path to the directory of the dll to the PATH environment variable.

Here are the results of dumpbin *which shows mangled names):

```
dumpbin /all TBarCode8.lib | findstr /c:"BCAlloc"
 B8B2 _BCAlloc@4
 B8B2 __imp__BCAlloc@4
    7 _BCAlloc@4
    7 __imp__BCAlloc@4
 Symbol name  : _BCAlloc@4
 Name         : BCAlloc
              _BCAlloc@4

dumpbin /all TBarCode8.dll | findstr /c:"BCAlloc"
      2    0 000247D9 BCAlloc
```

Questions: What does the suffix @4 mean in the mangled name? And how to solve this error LNK 2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: the dll of tbarcode I was provided is 32 bit, and I tried building my app in 64 bit. Building my app in 32 bit solved the problem.

Comment: The latest version of TBarCode SDK contains 64 bit libraries as well.